# IdeaVIm only works in src not Jar files

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

For some reason, I can use IdeaVim to navigate my source text just fine; however, when I jump to a java file (locked) in my external library, all Vim shortcuts are turned off somehow. How can I get them to continue functioning? I am using Intellij 14 CE.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-866 which I saw after updating IntelliJ from 14.0.2 to 14.0.3.  This needs to be fixed in IntelliJ.  Short of that, you could try changing the permissions on your external library source files, to make them writable.

Comment: Looks like VIM-866 lists [IDEA-135191](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-135191) as the root cause, and is (probably) fixed on master.  As a workaround: although 14.0.2 isn't listed on the [Previous Releases](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Previous+IntelliJ+IDEA+Releases) page, if you edit the URL for one of the existing relelases you can still download it: 14.0.2 [Mac](http://download.jetbrains.com/idea/ideaIU-14.0.2.dmg), [Windows](http://download.jetbrains.com/idea/ideaIU-14.0.2.exe), [Linux](http://download.jetbrains.com/idea/ideaIU-14.0.2.tar.gz), etc.